# Replace a string with other text only once in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

and I was having trouble with a certain function in my program. I'm trying to delete a SINGLE instance of a string of text in a textbox, instead of all instances of the string in the textbox.

Here is my code for the button that I want to execute this function in:

```
    If codon.Text.Contains(U.Text + "-") Then
        codon.Text = codon.Text.Replace(U.Text + "-", "")
    End If
```

So, this code replaces a string in codon.text with nothing, in other words, it deletes it.

[image: Here is the picture, for better context.]

When I click the button my cursor is hovering over, it deletes every instance of, say, UUG. I wanted to see if there was a way to delete only one instance of UUG.

Answer (score 2):

[String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2) doesn't offer much in terms of control over which part or how many parts of a string you can replace with another. It replaces all the specified substrings or chars (depending on which overload of the method is used) it encounters.

```
[TextBox].Text = [TextBox].Text.Replace("[SubString]", "")
```

Will replace all the `"[SubString]"` found with an empty string.

---

You could use [Regex.Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) to create a [MatchCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection?view=netframework-4.7.2) of elements that satisfy a condition given a String input and a value to match.

```
[result group] = Regex.Matches([InputString], [Match Pattern])
```

The `MatchCollection` will return a collection of [Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match?view=netframework-4.7.2) elements found.
Inspect the `[MatchCollection].Count` value to verify whether the search had any valid results.

Each `Match` identifies its status (boolean `Success`), the underlying `Value` (the Pattern) the `Index` position of `Value` inside the `[InputString]` and its `Length`.

An example: remove the second occurence of the string `"UUG-"` inside an `input` string:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim input As String = "UUG-AAA-UUG-CAC-ACC-GGG-GGG-"
Dim xMatches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(input, "UUG" & "-")

Dim output As String = input.Remove(xMatches(1).Index, xMatches(1).Length)
```

Result of `output`:

```
"UUG-AAA-CAC-ACC-GGG-GGG-"
```

You didn't specify which is the element in the input string that you want to remove. This method lets you choose which one using its `Index` position and/or the order in which it appears .

Comment: This works, but only up until there is only one string in the textbox. For instance, if I insert three "UUG"s in the textbox, then delete two, it gives me an exception when trying to delete the third one. Any ideas on how to fix this? I've tried clearing the textbox when there's only one item left, but it just threw an exception again.

Comment: @w60  Have you checked the `[MatchCollection].Count` property? If it's `= 1`, then there's just 1 element in the collection. This element in at Index `0`, not `1`. -- When you receive an `Exception`, you have to specify what exception that is. Is it a `IndexOutOfRange` exception?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to change the '1's in the "output" string to '0's. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: @w60 As a note: that Index (here: `xMatches([Index]))` lets you specify which one of the matches to remove. When you remove one element and retrieve the `output` string, you should also recreate the Matches collection using the new string as input if you want to remove another, otherwise the internal indexes positions will be out of sync.

Comment: Great alternative, how about providing an explanation of why the OP's code doesn't work in his case?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ  I think he knows :) However, why not; I'll write a note about that.

Comment: `I wanted to see if there was a way to delete only one instance`, I do not think he does as why would he be asking? Providing a clear explanation would benefit not only the OP, but anyone else that may come across this answer which would provide an alternative as well.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ  Note written. If you think something could be added to it, let me know.

Comment: @Jimi great explanation, this is beneficial to anyone seeing this answer, thanks for the update!

Answer (score 2):

You not working with string - you are working with collection of codes.
So consider full string as only format you will use for displaying codes you have, but operate on the collection.

Then your code will look much simpler and understandable for others (not as Regex ;))

```vb
Dim allCodes As New List(Of String) From { "UUG", "UUG", "CAC", "ACC", "GGG", "GGG" }

' Display all codes
codon.Text = String.Join("-", allCodes) 'output: UUG-UUG-CAC-ACC-GGG-GGG

' Remove the first appearance of given value
allCodes.Remove("UUG") ' allCodes => { "UUG", "CAC", "ACC", "GGG", "GGG" }
```

Simply one comprehensible line of code.
[List.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2) - *Removes the first occurrence of a specific object*

Other operations with your codes should become simple enough. Based on your logic you can use more then one collection and then have code which will convert those to the string for displaying it to the user.

If you want stick to the current implementation, then you can simply convert string to list of codes, remove first occurence and convert back to string.

```
Dim codes As String = "UUG-UUG-CAC-ACC-GGG-GGG-"

Dim list = codes.Split("-"c).ToList()
list.Remove("UUG")

codes = String.Join("-", list) 'output: UUG-CAC-ACC-GGG-GGG-
```

Comment: Downvoter - please explain, I will be glad to improve an answer or remove it.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Adding `List.RemoveAt()`, this is more likely what I would use.